# \setlength\itemsep throwing a weird bug

Tags: formatting, lists

I have to edit a LaTeX template for an assignment, which involves solving multiple choice questions. The code for one of these questions is as follows :

```
\begin{list}{$\square$}{}
\setlength\itemsep{-1.5em}
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
 other observations given the current state $y_t$\\
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
other states given the current state $y_t$\\
\item The current state $y_t$ is conditionally independent of all states given the previous state $y_{t-1}$\\
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of $x_{t-2}$ given the previous observation $x_{t-1}$.\\
\item None of the above
\end{list}
```

The problem with this is that I don't know how to mark my answers (only two of these choices are right, and should be marked with a black square). I've tried to remove the `{$\square$}` from the first line, and add `$\square$` next to each item, with `$\blacksquare$` next to the options I want marked.

```
\begin{list}{}
\setlength\itemsep{-1.5em}
\item $\square$ The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent 
 of all other observations given the current state $y_t$\\
\item $\square$ The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent 
 of all other states given the current state $y_t$\\
\item $\square$ The current state $y_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
 states given the previous state $y_{t-1}$\\
\item $\square$ The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent 
 of $x_{t-2}$ given the previous observation $x_{t-1}$.\\
\item $\square$ None of the above
\end{list}
```

And that worked for the previous question. But with this one, when I do it and compile, this happens. [image]

It's that pesky !-1.5em. And I don't know how to get rid of it. I tried removing the `\setlength\itemsep{-1.5em}` but that results in the spacing between items increasing to whatever the default value was and the contents of this page spill over onto the next one, which is unacceptable to the autograder. What do I do? It's incredibly annoying.

This is the error I get at the `\setlength\itemsep{-1.5em}` line. (I've tried putting the `\itemsep` in curly brackets too, as an answer said, to no avail.) [image]

Comment: The error message at the `\setlength\itemsep{-1.5em}` line is this :
Package calc error: `\topsep' invalid at this point. What is going on?

Comment: provide a _complete_  example which shows the error message. Using your code snippet with package `calc` gives _no_ error!

Comment: Leave out the `\\ `  at the end of the items and set `\setlength\itemsep{-.4em}`

Comment: To mark only the correct ones use `\item[$\blacksquare$]` only for the correct items and leave `{$\square$}` as the option of the `list` environment.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! That worked. Something to remember now for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `list` environment takes two arguments and in your second example you are only feeding it one. It therefore uses the next token, which is `\setlength`, as its second argument. Using `\begin{list}{}{}` instead of `\begin{list}{}` therefore removes the error.

As for the problem you were originally trying to solve: the `\item` macro has an optional argument which you can use to specify its label. The following should thus do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} %% <- for \square and \blacksquare

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{$\square$}{}
\setlength\itemsep{-.4em}
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
 other observations given the current state $y_t$
\item[$\blacksquare$] The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
other states given the current state $y_t$
\item[$\blacksquare$] The current state $y_t$ is conditionally independent of all states given the previous state $y_{t-1}$
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of $x_{t-2}$ given the previous observation $x_{t-1}$.
\item None of the above
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You could save yourself some typing by e.g. defining

```
\newcommand*\correctitem{\item[$\blacksquare$]}
```

and using that instead of typing it out every time.

---

---

Incidentally, the contents of the second argument of `list` is executed right before the start of the actual list. 
It would be more appropriate to put `\setlength\itemsep{-.4em}` inside this argument, like this:

```
\begin{list}{$\square$}{\setlength\itemsep{-.4em}}
```

For `\itemsep` it makes little difference, but if you want to set e.g. `\topsep`, doing this inside the environment is actually too late.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did work. I shall keep this in mind now, especially that last trick.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of going crazy setting the `\itemsep` you could use `enumitem` package with `nosep` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\square$}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
 other observations given the current state $y_t$
\item[$\blacksquare$] The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of all 
other states given the current state $y_t$
\item[$\blacksquare$] The current state $y_t$ is conditionally independent of all states given the previous state $y_{t-1}$
\item The current observation $x_t$ is conditionally independent of $x_{t-2}$ given the previous observation $x_{t-1}$.
\item None of the above
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]